# getting error message while trying to publish web application on server having crystal reports

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

Hi I am trying to publish my website on the server which is having crystal reports. I am continuously getting an error message

"Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I have tried everything.. tried searching a lots of forum but couldn't find a solution. The application is working fine on localhost, but when I publish it on server I am getting this error message. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and crystal reports basic for visual studio 2008.

I have tried publishing in .net2.0 and .net 3.5 but still get the same error message. I am publishing my first web application so any help would be greatly appreciated.

you can see the error at www.vcsenterprise.com/cr7/

Also I am hosting on a shared server and the hosting provider have informed me that they support crystal reports 10.

Thanks and Regards,

Arpit Mittal

Comment: Have you installed CR Runtimes in the GAC?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Crystal Reports 2008 Runtime Package for the .NET Framework from [here](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#08) and install it on your server. This should solve your problem. I had the same issue when deploying one of my applications on a server without the runtime files.